# Why can't the params parameter take multi-dimensional array as parameter C#

Tags: c#

This question might be annoying. I would really love if you could help me.

So the below code is all fine:

```
public void jj(int g, params int[][] h) {

}
```

whilst, this is not fine:

```
public void jj(int g, params int[,] h) {

}
```

Can you please tell me why the params parameter take multi-dimensional array as parameter whilst It can, in case of jagged arrays?

Comment: How would the compiler infer how many dimensions your array has, when you can only provide a comma separated list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea of `params` is that in the calling code you can write multiple separate arguments, each being of the argument type, and the compiler will create an array for you. So you could have:

```cs
public void SomeMethod(params int[] numbers) { ... }

SomeMethod(1, 2, 3);
```

The compiler would convert that call into something like:

```cs
SomeMethod(new int[] { 1, 2, 3 });
```

For a single-dimensional array, that's straightforward - but what would it do if you had that same method call with an `int[,]` parameter?

In your "array of arrays" example, it's still easy enough - because each argument would still need to be an `int` array, for example, in this code:

```cs
public void SomeMethod(params int[] numbers) { ... }

int[] x1 = { 1, 2, 3 };
int[] x2 = { 4, 5, 6 };
SomeMethod2(x1, x2);
```

... the method call is equivalent to `SomeMethod2(new int[][] { x1, x2 });`.

But you can't create an `int[,]` directly from multiple single-dimensional arrays. (You can create the rectangular array and then copy the contents of the single-dimensional arrays, but that's not the same thing at all.)

Answer (score 2):

Short answer? Because that's how the spec is defined: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0225

Long answer: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37610411/using-params-keyword-with-a-multidimensional-array#:~:text=params%20isn't%20about%20passing,be%20a%20one%20dimensional%20array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37610411/using-params-keyword-with-a-multidimensional-array#:%7E:text=params%20isn%27t%20about%20passing,be%20a%20one%20dimensional%20array).

> params isn't about passing multi dimensional data, it's about passing a variable number of arguments to a function. Since that list of arguments is inherently one dimensional that's why the type has to be a one dimensional array.

Comment: To be honest, I would love the long answer)

Answer (score 1):

For the first example, the parameter type is `int[]`, an array of integers.

What would you expect as parameter type for the second example?`